# Почему не выводится первый результат?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Таблица (результат запроса в менеджере sql)

```
stats
---
| found_query       | COUNT(found_query) | 
| ------------------|------------------- | 
| Дракон            | 2                  | 
| Дракон Ла-Тринита | 1                  | 
| Гвиллионы         | 1                  |
```

PHP:

```
$sth = $dbh->query( "SELECT found_query, COUNT(found_query) FROM stats GROUP BY found_query ORDER BY COUNT(found_query) DESC;");
$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
$text = "Статистика:\n";

while ($row = $sth->fetch()) {
    $text .= PHP_EOL.$row[0]." : ".$row[1];
}
```

Вывод:

```
Статистика:

Дракон Ла-Тринита : 1
Гвиллионы : 1
```

Почему не выводится первое значение поля `Дракон`?

Comment: потому что выводите в цикле, а первый `fetch` делаете сразу после выполнения запроса. уберите этот fetch вне цикла, и будет вам то, что хотите

Comment: Да, верно, заметил уже, что первый fetch лишний, спасибо